# Connect remote PC via VPN or different solution?

Tags: windows, networking, mac, vpn

I have remote PC in another country and I need it to be shared over local network, including usb printers and different devices. How can I connect it via VPN? Is there any native over-internet solutions, other than using a VPN to connect to private network? I need secure access for private data sharing.

Using Windows (local network) and Mac (remote PC).

Comment: What you need is a VPN Software (you can use SoftEther which is simple), and share stuff across your network. Please explain what kind of devices you want to share, so we can propose a suitable software.

Comment: I want to share usb devices over network. (printers, usb drives, etc.)

Comment: Printers and external drives can be shared inside a network, but some other devices cannot. Please be specific on the shared devices so we have more input in order to provide a solution.